# Can I re-install Windows 7 English with an activated product key for another language?

Tags: windows-7, product-key

My computer came with Turkish Windows 7 Professional installed. So I wanted to install the English version.

Is it possible to use the existing, activated product key on the box to install English version?

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks. You are right, there is no legit way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to change the language.

The one and only way to do is using Visualizer which is not supported by Microsoft since it's a hack.